# Why is window.location way faster in FF than in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, redirect

I'm using this code to redirect people to some URLs depending on their browser language of choice.

As you'll see, if they have a german browser, no change will occur.
If they have an english, french, or spanish browser, they will be redirected to the proper URLs.

This only happens once in a browser session so they are able to reach the german home, if needed, from another language.

```
<?php 

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['visitedOnce'])){

    if(is_home() && ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'de' ){

        $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
        switch ($lang){
            case "de":
                //echo "PAGE DE";
                break;
            case "en":
                //echo "PAGE EN";
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://www.google.com";</script>';
                break;
            case "es":
                //echo "PAGE ES";
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://www.google.es";</script>';
                break;        
            case "fr":
                //echo "PAGE FR";
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://www.google.fr";</script>';
                break;        
            default:
                //echo "PAGE EN - Setting Default";
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://www.google.com";</script>';
                break;
        }

    }

    $_SESSION['visitedOnce'] = true;
}
?>
```

In Firefox is working fine, the HTML won't load, and the redirect will occur seamlessly.

However, Google Chrome shows ugly chunks of unstyled HTML before the redirect occurs.

Is there a way to prevent it using this kind of javascript redirect?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you doing the redirect in JavaScript rather than returning a 301 or 302 redirect?

Comment: How about using a proper server-side redirect instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And what about doing redirect right in the PHP? Then you will see no ugly chunks of unstyled HTML... Just be careful, you have no output before `header('Location: http://www.google.***');`.

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['visitedOnce'])){
    $_SESSION['visitedOnce'] = true;

    if(is_home() && ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'de' ){
        $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
        switch ($lang){
            case "de":
                //echo "PAGE DE";
                break;
            case "en":
                //echo "PAGE EN";
                header('Location: http://www.google.com');
                exit;
                //echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://www.google.com";</script>';
                //break;
            case "es":
                //echo "PAGE ES";
                header('Location: http://www.google.es');
                exit;
                //echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://www.google.es";</script>';
                //break;        
            case "fr":
                //echo "PAGE FR";
                header('Location: http://www.google.fr');
                exit;
                //echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://www.google.fr";</script>';
                //break;        
            default:
                //echo "PAGE EN - Setting Default";
                header('Location: http://www.google.com');
                exit;
                //echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://www.google.com";</script>';
                //break;
        }

    }

    //$_SESSION['visitedOnce'] = true;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

> However, Google Chrome shows ugly chunks of unstyled HTML before the redirect occur.
>   Is there a way to prevent it using this kind of javascript redirect?

have your html document look like this

```
<body style="display:none;">
...
<script>
    document.body.style.display = '';
</script>
</body>
```